# How should I vectorize the following list of lists with scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I would like to vectorize with scikit learn a list who has lists. I go to the path where I have the training texts I read them and then I obtain something like this:

```
corpus = [["this is spam, 'SPAM'"],["this is ham, 'HAM'"],["this is nothing, 'NOTHING'"]]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')
vect_representation= vect.fit_transform(corpus)
print vect_representation.toarray()
```

And I get the following:

```
return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Also the problem with this are the labels at the end of each document, how should I treat them in order to do a correct classification?.

Comment: Just read your post because i had a similar problem. My error was: corpus shouldnt be a list of list, it should be a list of strings, like this: corpus = ["this is spam","this is ham",...]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For everybody in the future this solve my problem:

```
corpus = [["this is spam, 'SPAM'"],["this is ham, 'HAM'"],["this is nothing, 'NOTHING'"]]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
bag_of_words = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda doc: doc, lowercase=False).fit_transform(splited_labels_from_corpus)
```

And this is the output, when I use the `.toarray()` function:

```
[[0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]]
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Could anybody recommend me a more pythonic way to do this?. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: you don't need two `CountVectorizers`, also why does your input data  is always so strangely mixed with the labels?

Comment: Sorry, the first `vect` was an error. I did not realize of it (I just copy and paste the code of the question) I will edit the answer. I have that format since I'm just learning how to use scikit learn with my own corpus and I'm assuming that I have a corpus in that way one document per list. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: The data is always mixed with labels because I don't know any other way to label the training data. What other way to label the training data do you recommend me assuming that i have training data in lists where each list is one document?. How can I tell the classification algorithm that one document belongs to a class?.

Comment: Normally the data comes from .csv files where each line correspond to a sample/document and the last or the first columns are the labels. This is easy to deal with using pandas. If you are inputting your data manually then put your labels directly in a `y` list variable like `y=['SPAM', 'HAM', ...]` with a length equal to the number of documents, i.e. don't mixe them with your documents. Then your corpus would be `corpus = [ "this is spam", "this is ham", ...]`

Comment: This gives the output of different dimensions. This gives erroneous results.

Answer (score 3):

First you should separate labels from texts. If you want to use CountVectorizer you have to transform your texts one by one:

```
corpus = [["this is spam, 'SPAM'"],["this is ham, 'HAM'"],["this is nothing, 'NOTHING'"]]
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
... split labels from texts
vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')
vect_representation= map(vect.fit_transform,corpus)
...
```

As another option, you can use [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) with list of lists directly.

Comment: So should I split the labels from text?. I was thinking on use a supervised aproach(MNB, SVM, LR) and using `corpus` as training data, if I drop the labels, how can I use them to train a classifier?. Or this will be solved with the `y` that the tutorials that scikit provide(target)

Comment: Yes, usually y stands for list of labels in scikit. So you have to split the corpus to X and Y.

Comment: I split the labels but when I do the following: ´vect_representation.toarray()´ I have the following: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toarray` I would like to visualize the document term matrix. One vector per document, how to aproach this? thanks

Comment: vect_representation is list of vectors. You can visualize by toarray()  each vector in the list.

Comment: "As another option, you can use TfidfVectorizer with list of lists directly.", how exactly? Doesn't work for me.