# Vectorizing a list of lists with sklearn learn?

Tags: python, countvectorizer

I am trying to use **CountVectorizer** from sklearn with a list of lists.

```
Lst=[['apple','peach','mango'],['apple','apple','mango']]
```

I would like the output to return the count of words in each list.
For example:

```
0:apple:1
0:peach:1
0:mango:1

1:apple:2
1:peach:0
1:mango:1
```

or any other format.

I found this post that is similar to mine, but the answer wasn't complete.

[How should I vectorize the following list of lists with scikit learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673527/how-should-i-vectorize-the-following-list-of-lists-with-scikit-learn)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst=[['apple','peach','mango'],['apple','apple','mango']]
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> {i:Counter(v) for i,v in enumerate(lst)}
{0: Counter({'apple': 1, 'peach': 1, 'mango': 1}),
 1: Counter({'apple': 2, 'mango': 1})}
```

To get in the expected format(in list)

```
>>> [[i, obj, count] for i,v in enumerate(lst) for obj,count in Counter(v).items()]
[[0, 'apple', 1],
 [0, 'peach', 1],
 [0, 'mango', 1],
 [1, 'apple', 2],
 [1, 'mango', 1]]
```